# Replacing all values in a data frame with random values within a specified range

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe in R that (with the exception of ID variables) only has values from 0-1.

Example:

```
v_11_01     v_11_02     v_11_03     v_11_04     v_11_05
0.759670859 0.630213804 0.674940162 0.711895064 0.719449533
0.759670859 0.630213804 0.69626758  0.712106042 0.787841507
0.759670859 0.630213804 0.69626758  0.712106042 0.787841507
0.759670859 0.630213804 0.69626758  0.713579989 0.787841507
```

I want to replace all of the values (with the exception of ID variables) with randomly generate values between 0-1. What is the best method for doing this?

Comment: try `df1[] <-  lapply(df1, runif)`

Comment: `runif` is vectorized. You can just do `df[] <- runif(prod(dim(df)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can loop through the columns and get values from uniform distribution.  By default, the `min` and `max` are 0 and 1 respectively.

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, runif)
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    mutate_each(funs(runif))
```